# How to set a background for wrapped text?

Tags: css

I need to set a background for a wrapped text.
Is there a way to get this effect via css http://oi40.tinypic.com/ydlk4.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple solution

http://jsfiddle.net/69RWL/

```
a {
    display:inline;
    color:white;
    padding:5px 0px;
    line-height:30px;
    background:black;
    font-size:18px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text in `<span></span>`.

Or add `display: inline-block` with`<div></div>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uNjT6/1/

Comment: Gorgeous! Is there any way do not use <br /> element. But if not, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: inline;` to your element whatever it is div or p, etc.

Comment: Great! Is there a way to get the same effect from right to left. Alignt text to right.

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
    /* like this */
    padding: 1px 0;
    /* or */
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;

}
```